# Expandable listview with Root Header

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I need an expandable list view with root header Essential and Other. Further Essential will have many header like India, Pakistan, etc,. On-clicking India I will expand and show States  India like Delhi, Gujarat, Rajasthan, etc.

It is basically like

```
Essential
|
|-India
-----*****
-----*****
-----*****
-----*****
|-Pakisthan
-----*****
-----*********
Others
|
|-USA
-----*****
-----*****
-----*****
-----**********
|-UK
-----*****
-----*********
```

[image]

How to make header like Essentials and Other on Expandable list view ?

Comment: Refer this link. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: @HasmukhBarochiya this library is not able to import into my project on Android studio. Can you specify the gradle

Comment: Working fine with Gradle. Please check sample app and description with library for how to integrate.